# iOS: problem with NSDate and NSDateComponent

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, nstimeinterval

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setTimeZone:[ NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(+0*3600) ] ] ;
[components setYear:2011];
[components setDay:13];
[components setMonth:5];
NSDate *date1 = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];


    NSTimeInterval diff = [data2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
    NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", diff];
    int second = [intervalString intValue];
    int period = second/3600/24; 
    NSLog(@"period:%d", period);
    NSLog(@"date1:%@", data1);
    NSLog(@"date2:%@", data2);
```

In consol the result is:

2011-05-12 10:57:00.406 Project[297:707] period:0;

2011-05-12 10:57:00.375 Project[297:707] data2:2011-05-12 08:56:52 +0000

2011-05-12 10:57:00.402 Project[297:707] data1:2011-05-13 00:00:00 +0000

I don't understand why period is "0", it must be "1"; Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSTimeInterval is just a double, so you shouldn't need to convert it to a string then back to an int.

What happens if you do something like this:

```
NSTimeInterval diff = [data2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
int period = (int)diff/3600/24; 
NSLog(@"period:%d", period);
```

Also if the interval is diff is less than 3600*24 the result of diff/3600/24 will be less than 1, so the int value will be flattened to 0.

Comment: then I must use an instruction that add a value every time period (double) have numbers after point. example if I have 1,01 it must be 2 or if i have 4,67 it must be 5....right?

Comment: How about making period a double?  Then you won't lose any precision.

Answer (score 0):

date2 is the *current* date. No idea why `period` *should* be one here.

At the time of this writing, diff is approx. -53000. Dividing it brings it to zero as you get and is expected.

Also keep in mind that NSTimeInterval is a floating point number, and you are converting it through a string to an integer, which will drop off the fractions.

And there is *no point* in doing this conversion through a string - just use `int seconds = (int) diff;`.

Please copy/paste your code *directly*, as you refer to `data1`and `data2`, but your variables are called `date1` and `date2`. But then, this might already be your bug, if those variables are declared elsewhere.